# Javascript: Detect load in ascx page. Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, internet-explorer, ascx

I have a dropdown that will trigger the ChangeGraph javascript function.  In Chrome/Firefox, when my partial view (.ascx) is loaded, I get the hello alert.  This is not the case in IE.  Any ideas on how to solve this.  Basically I can't initiate a javascript function once the ascx page is written using "$('#GraphForm').html(data);"

From my Index.aspx:

```
<div id="GraphForm"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function ChangeGraph(displayTypeId) {
    $('#GraphForm').html("");

    $.get('/Dashboard/GetGraphForm', { id: displayTypeId }, function(data) {
        $('#GraphForm').html(data);        
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult GetGraphForm(int id)
{
    //... Build Model (removed)

    return PartialView("EnergyConsumedFormView"/* , model */);
}
```

EnergyConsumedFormView.ascx Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to javascript so the answer wasn't obvious until I figured it out.  Know it seems REAL obvious.  Just call the function if you don't care if the document is ready...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('hello');
</script>
```